# Phottix Strato TTL Flash Trigger Minolta/Multi Interface shoe

Tags: sony, wireless-triggers

I own a set of Phottix Strato™ II Multi 5-in-1 Wireless Flash Trigger for Sony (Minolta shoe).

> http://www.phottix.com/en/phottix-strato-ii-multi.html

Is it possible to trigger these Strato II receivers using a Sony A77II with Strato TTL Flash Trigger for Canon

> http://www.phottix.com/en/strato-ttl-flash-trigger-set-for-canon-nikon.html

in the Sony Multi Interface hot shoe?